# Need to add three entities to database with two 1-* relationships

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I need to call SaveChanges() once
Here is my model (simplified):

|Publisher| 1 ------- * |Book| * --------1 |Location|

Here is what I'm doing:

```
void AddBook(Publisher pub, Location loc) {
  Book b = Book.CreateBook(0,...);
  context.AddRelatedObject(pub, "Books", b);
  context.AddToLocations(loc);
  context.AddLink(loc, "Books", b);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

this throws exception:

Entities in 'Context.Books' participate in the 'LocationBook' relationship. 0 related 'Location' were found. 1 'Location' is expected

The context here is WCF Data context (using web service reference)

Under debugger i can see Entities for Book and Location and Link for Location->Book

Appreciate if you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use context.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOption.Batch).
Without that it will send each update as a separate request and the server will try to apply each of those requests separately to the DB. If there are foreign key constrains this will fail.
With Batch the client will send everything in one request and server will apply it all at once, which should work.